# DotNetOpenAuth Won't Build on TFS 2010 Build

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am trying to setup a TFS 2010 build definition for an MVC4 Application and found an issue with DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055.

The build process throws the following HTTP 503 errors!?  I am really not sure what the issue is because the source files are in the build folder as expected.

Thanks for reading my post!

```
D:\TFSBuilds\1\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Stage\Sources\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Main\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055.nuspec: Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

 D:\TFSBuilds\1\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Stage\Sources\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Main\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055.nupkg: Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

 D:\TFSBuilds\1\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Stage\Sources\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Main\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055\lib
et35-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.xml: Please contact your administrator.  There was an error contacting the server. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

 D:\TFSBuilds\1\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Stage\Sources\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Main\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055\lib
et35-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.dll: Please contact your administrator.  There was an error contacting the server. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

 D:\TFSBuilds\1\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Stage\Sources\MyMVC4WebApp\MyMVC4WebApp-Main\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.4.2.2.13055\lib
et40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.dll: Please contact your administrator.  There was an error contacting the server. Technical information (for administrator):   HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

 One or more errors occurred while performing a Get operation.
```

Comment: I am not sure what this was about but rebooting the build machine cleared it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NuGet Package Restore was enabled and it was having trouble connecting to the NuGet stream to check for new packages.